# Linking in localhost(LAMP)

Tags: linux, apache2, server, lamp

I am newly(about 1 month) started using LAMP and Bootstrap.

I developed a web-site that worked perfectly until I reinstalled LAMP.

Here my progress:

```
0. reinstalled LAMP
1. moved my "backup-ed" file to my "localhost" direction
2. I run "chmod 777 *"  to each dir and file
3. When I write "localhost" to my browser(firefox) the "index.html" is running 
4. When I click the link(say: <a href="index.html">index</a>)
```

The browser responds:

```
http://localhost/undefined
```

---

```
Not Found

The requested URL /undefined was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Is there any way to fix this, by the way it's working(linking) perfectly when I write file:///var/www/html/index.html.

The reason why I want to use LAMP is add .php files to handle form.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you do hit http://localhost ?
What exactly do you see?? Tried http://localhost/html

What is exactly your document root as per apache conf?

Comment: When I hit http://localhost the "index.html" is opening correctly on browser, but when I click any link in that page(which is opened correctly) the address bar shows http://localhost/undefined

Comment: Ok..great..now gimme the folder structure i mean the location of other file is it in same location where index.html is? And share the href code u have inside index.html

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check that you are placing your files in the root directoy. It should be in the "htdocs" foler.
/opt/lampp/htdocs/

If all else fails, you can try using xampp which is another free alternative to lamp.

Answer (score 0):

I get this a lot, when your browser looks for a file that is not in htaccess you get a forbidden or unfound error. The way to fix this is to make sure the link you click goes to an accessible URL. Try finding if other links in the page or scripts are overwriting your link.
Finally check if you can access it from another browser, or try to demonstrate the security of your machine. From a public library you can request an Ubuntu CD from canonical, and while you're waiting, you can visually inspect your machine for tampering.